# Centering column values in a table that's already centered?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn, columns

I am working with the following code for a table :

```
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lllll }
    \toprule
     \textbf{\mytab{DM}}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\mytab{Epistemic $>$ Root}}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\mytab{Root $>$ Epistemic}}}\\
      \midrule
       & \textbf{\mytab{E--E}} & \textbf{\mytab{E--R}} & \textbf{\mytab{R--R}} &  \textbf{\mytab{R--E}} \\
      \midrule 
      \textit{\mytab{Must Used to (...)\\ Will Ought to}} & .27 & .25 & .23 & .22\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Proportions of semantic ordering of DMs with 5 tokens or less, from \textit{Must Used to} to \textit{Will Ought to} (n=59)}
    \label{tab:low_freq_DM_semantics}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
```

[image]

As can be seen in the output, the values in the second column (Root > Epistemic) are left-aligned and I would like to center them within that large column to make them stand out from the values in the first. I have tried using `\centering` inside the column but also manual commands like `\hskip`, `\qquad`, but nothing happens when I do this. Would appreciate some help as I sometimes struggle wrapping my head around Latex tables, although I expect the solution to this problem is pretty simple!

All the best,

Cameron

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is. We don't know, how `\mytab` is defined nor which `\documentcalss` you use etc.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind? The third column has been made artificially larger by enclosing its header in a wider box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
\textbf{DM} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Epistemic $>$ Root}} &
  {\textbf{Root $>$ Epistemic}}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
& {\textbf{E--E}} & {\makebox[6em]{\textbf{E--R}}} & {\textbf{R--R}} &  {\textbf{R--E}} \\
\midrule 
\textit{Might Can}   & .27 & .25 & .23 & .22 \\
\textit{Might Could} & .34 & .66 & 0   & 0   \\
\textit{Can Could}   & .24 & 0   & .75 & 0   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Proportions of semantic ordering of DMs with 5 tokens or less, 
  from \textit{Must Used to} to \textit{Will Ought to} ($n=59$)}
\label{tab:low_freq_DM_semantics}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Always keep the leading zero in front of decimal numbers. As you see, `siunitx` does this automatically anyway.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pure guessing ...

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\itshape}l SSSS }
    \toprule
\thead{DM}
    & \mcc[3]{\textbf{Epistemic $>$ Root}}
            &  \mcc{\thead{Root $>$ Epistemic}}                     \\
      \cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-5}
    &{\thead{E--E}} &{\thead{E--R}} &{\thead{R--R}} &{\thead{R--E}}\\
      \midrule
\makecell[l]{Must Used to (...)\\
          Will Ought to   }
    & .27           & .25           & .23           & .22\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Proportions of semantic ordering of DMs with 5 tokens or less, from \textit{Must Used to} to \textit{Will Ought to} (n=59)}
\label{tab:low_freq_DM_semantics}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, pretty close to what I was looking for!